# How to modify an array and add new element to array state on react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, select, state, element

I'm new in React bassed on functions (no classes), trying to get an array from a component using state redux, and add it to a new array because I need just two properties to add elements to a multiple Select component.
I tried diferent things but no luck. I will aprectiate any help. Here is my code:

```
const FormInfo = () => {

    //reading an array from another component
    const arrayFromOtherComponent = useSelector(state => state.otherComponente.array);

    //creating a local state with empty array
    const [state, setState] = useState([]);

    //creating new state to add this object to the array state
    const [ item, setItem ] = useState({
        value: '',
        label: ''
    })

    //looping arrayFromOtherComponent to get some properties and add to state
    const callSelect = () => {
        arrayFromOtherComponent.map( var => (
            setItem({
                value: '`{var.id}`',            -> I cant' read the var object
                label: '`{var.name}`'           -> I cant' read the var object
            }),
            setState( state.concat(item) )      -> Is not updating the array state
        ));
    }

    //Calling function to update array
    useEffect ( () => {
        if(arrayFromOtherComponent){
            callSelect() }
    }, []);
    .
    .
    .

    //Using a Multiple Select to return the info
    return (
        .
        .
        .
            <Select
                isMulti
                options={state}       -> this should iterate the array state to show options
                value={state.selectedOption}
                onChange={handleChange}
                closeMenuOnSelect={false}
            />
        .
        .
        .

    );
}
export default FormInfo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

callSelect method could be like this:

```
const callSelect = () => {
    const initialArray = arrayFromOtherComponent.map((element) => {
      return {
        value: element.id,
        label: element.name
      };
    });
    setState(initialArray);
  };
```

Comment: Thank you Anass, this worked. You taught me another approach that I did not consider. Best regards !!

Comment: You're welcome @DiegoBenedetto  good luck .

Answer (score 0):

```js
const callSelect = () => {
    arrayFromOtherComponent.map( var => (
        setItem({
            value: `${var.id}`,            //Use $ before {} and just inside `` not inside '``'
            label: `${var.name}`           
        }),
        setState( state.concat(item) )      -> Is not updating the array state
    ));
}
```

Please elaborate more what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you a lot Sanskar, but still is not working. I'm trying to add more code but I have this message "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted". This is my first post, sorry. Meanwhile I can say you that even if I use this:
SetItem({ value: 'a', label: 'a'}) 
The "item" and "state" still remains empty at this way: 
     item: {"value":"","label":""}  
     state: []
I'm seeing this thru the console log

Comment: Thank you Sanskar, you taught me about how to do it assignig value: `${var.id}`, maybe for my logic code it didn't work now, but it's very useful for me in the future.